# How to find the “odd one out” in a list of numbers

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have an array of numbers [x1, x2, x3, etc] that is size is over 20 elements and I'm trying to put together an algorithm to sort the elements based on the "oddness" they have relative to the rest of the list.

I'm defining the "oddness" as the distance from the barycenters, given some threshold T1. The barycenters are where the values tend to concentrate, possibly given some second threshold T2.

**Example:** [20, 20, 21, 31, 24, 20, 70, 21, 31, 24, 20, 20, 21, 31, 24, 20, 20, 21, 31, 24] and T1=10 The barycenter is about 24 and only odd one out is 70

This case is trivial as the familiar "distance from the mean or median" metric will do eg. d(70)=|24-70|=46>10=T1 and d(31)=|24-31|=7<10=T1

I can't quite figure out how to deal with the more general case of having 2 or more barycenters.

**Example 2:** [20, 20, 21, 31, 24, 20, 70, 21, 31, 24, 120, 120, 121, 131, 124, 120, 120, 121, 131, 124] Now there are two barycenters d1=24 and d2=124 and the only odd one is still 70

But the previous metric breaks apart. Maybe the hard part is to figure out which are the barycenters.

*Note: I'm looking for a fast algorithm rather than an accurate one*

Comment: The problem you are looking for is identifying outliers in a k-cluster data. I recommend looking at  [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4c68/4a9ba057fb7e61733ff554fe2975a2c91096.pdf) article it has a way of dealing with it and using matlab can speed up the vectorizations if you want to program the algorithm.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement that you want "a fast algorithm rather than an accurate one." If you're prepared to tolerate some level of approximation, you need to explain what that is.

Comment: Assuming barycenters are 24 and 124 I dont mind 10 or 40 being classified as odd/outliers  but I mind 22 or 26. I am not sure how to define this formally though.